# Find and replace in div table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text "First Name (Given Name, Forename):" that needs to replaced with "Something" using jquery. Please see below text.

```
  <div id="ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch" 
               sizcache="3" sizset="0">
    <table width="100%" sizcache="2" sizset="0">
        <tbody sizcache="1" sizset="0">
            <tr sizcache="0" sizset="0">
                <td style="width: 40%;">
                    First Name (Given Name, Forename): //replace with "Something"
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
```

How to do this?

Comment: **Exactly** which text should be replaced by which other text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a class on your td (tdContent) you could do something like this:

```
$("#ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch .tdContent").html("New Content goes here");
```

If you do not want to use a class make your selector

```
$("#ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch td:first")
```

The simplest would be to give the td an id:

```
$("#tdID").html("content");
```

Comment: this is working $("#ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch td:first"). But I have another <TD> at 4th place. How to replace that?

Comment: If your content is not dynamic, I would give each td an id (td1, td1 but with better names for the id).  Then use  $("#td1").html() and  $("#td2").html() respectively.

Comment: i can not give #ID. This built in sharepoint page. I can not customize it.

Comment: If the td is not runat="server" then you should be able to give them ids.  If not, give both of them a class (tdContent) and do $(".tdContent:eq(0)") and $(".tdContent:eq(1)").

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
var text = $('td:contains("(Given Name, Forename)")');
text.html(text.html().replace('(Given Name, Forename)', "Something"));
```

### update

```
$('td:contains("Company Name")').html('Something')
```

Comment: I dont understand this apply all place where (Given Name, Forename) not there. ex: "Company Name:" replacing with "Something"

Comment: Will you always be replacing the same thing?

Comment: It is replace all <td> texts. where I have "Company Name" also replacing with "Something"

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to find the DOM element and then use jQuery's text (or html) method.

```
$('div#ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch td').text('Something')
```

Comment: the whole page became "something". no more controls

Comment: Do you have other table cells in that table? div#ctl00_m_g_23e3c2e9_71b9_464f_9ad3_46a603eb384f_ctl00_PanelSearch td will match all td's within that div. If you want to only target that cell you'll have to add some sort of hook like @john-kalberer suggests above (most often an id or a class).

Comment: @john-kalberer idea is working for my first <td>. But I have samething in 4th <td>. I added td:fourth, but it is not working.

Comment: Yeah td:fourth won't work. I would set a class on the fields that needs to be replaced. It'll make the syntax much shorter too. See this example [http://jsfiddle.net/PdeaR/](http://jsfiddle.net/PdeaR/)